# How to change "default" Jenkins build status label on GitHub?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-github-plugin

**What do I have**:

1. Jenkins job (Freestyle Project). Job trigger is `GitHub Pull Request Builder`
2. GitHub repository
3. Webhook to trigger the Jenkins job

**What do I want**: change "default" label from the screenshot below to something more specific, lets say, "Codestyle"

[image]

, so the text will be "Codestyle - Build finished."

**What have I tried**: adding GitHub commit status
[image]
It resulted in two build statuses:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround ([reference](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/407#issuecomment-248668043)):

1. GitHub Pull Request Builder -> Application Setup:
   [image]
2. Job -> Build Triggers -> Trigger Setup
   [image]

Result:

[image]

To keep build statuses, I removed `--none--` from "Commit Status Build Triggered" and "Commit Status Build Started" fields.

Answer (score -1):

Build triggers ==> Trigger Setup ==> Commit Status Context ==> Here specify the name and it will appear on the github.